# Retrieving changes made by a Java Agent on a document

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I am passing parameters to a Java agent from Lotus Script like this:

```
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase    
Set doc = db.CreateDocument     
Set uiDoc = workspace.CurrentDocument

Call doc.AppendItemValue("fileName", "SomeString" )
Call doc.Save(True, False)

Set MyAgent = db.GetAgent("AgentName")
Call MyAgent.Run(doc.NoteID)    
Set session = New NotesSession
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase

result = doc.GetItemValue("Result")(0)
```

The agent says the following in Java:

```
Session session = getSession();
AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
Agent agent = agentContext.getCurrentAgent();
Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
Document doc = db.getDocumentByID(agent.getParameterDocID());
String fileName = doc.getItemValueString("fileName");
doc.appendItemValue("Result","MyResult");
doc.save();
```

The agent is doing his job correctly. I checked the parameter document and it indeed contains the results from the agent. However, my form is not able to read the Result parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to **save** the doc in your Java code and to **re-read** your doc in LotusScript after calling your agent.

It is easier to use [an In-Memory Document](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_and_Calling_Agents_Using_an_In-Memory_Document) though:

LotusScript

```
MyAgent.RunWithDocumentContext(doc, doc.NoteID)
```

Java

```
Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext()
```

Comment: Ah, you saved me again, Knut.

Comment: a small caveat if you are using the extractFile() method, saved my bottom: http://blog.redturtle.it/authors/andrea

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you cannot use `RunWithDocumentContext` (in earlier versions of Lotus Notes) then you need to reopen document:

```vb
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set doc = db.CreateDocument

Call doc.AppendItemValue("fileName", "SomeString" )
Call doc.Save(True, False)

noteID$ = doc.NoteID

Set MyAgent = db.GetAgent("AgentName")
Call MyAgent.Run(noteID$)

'Delete document from memory.
Delete doc

'Get updated document.
Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID(noteID$)
result = doc.GetItemValue("Result")(0)
```