# Multithreading a java agent

Tags: java, multithreading, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

A java agent has to upload a file in the background and return the Url of the uploaded file. While uploading, the agent has to report its progress.

I marked the agent to be "Run in background client thread.

I am stuck in the following dilemma:

- I can run the agent from Lotus Script and pass its parameters in an In-Memory file, but the client actually doesn't run in its own thread. Instead, it blocks the whole client.
- I can run the agent from a formula, but then I can't pass any parameters!
- If I use Lotus Script and take care of the threading on my own in Java, my thread doesn't even get started!

I've read that the [Notes client doesn't support multithreading](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/3c005048d98917d68525704a00420a23?OpenDocument). But I can't make the agent RunOnServer because it is accessing a web server available only for the client.

This is related to [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733460/reloading-a-document-while-being-changed-by-an-agent-running-in-the-background) by the way.

Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: I would appreciate any explanation for the down vote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't make the agent `RunOnServer` then you can use `LS2J` instead of agent. Create your own class with threading and use its properties.
Here is example with custom `Java Class` and `Java Timer`:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Test
{
    private boolean _isOver;
    private int _counter;
    private Timer _timer;
    private String _url; 

    public Test()
    {
        _timer = new Timer("Timer");
    }

    public void Start() //Add parameters here that you want to use in Java
    {
        _counter = 0;
        _isOver = false;
        _url = "";

        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {   
                if (_counter++ == 9)
                {
                    _isOver = true;

                    _timer.cancel();

                    _url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
                }
            }
        };

        _timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 30, 5000);
    }

    public int getCounter() { return _counter; }
    public boolean getIsOver() { return _isOver; }
    public String getURL() { return _url; }
}
```

In `LotusScript` add global `LS2J` variables:

```vb
(Options)
Uselsx "*javacon"
Use "MyJavaLibrary"

(Declarations)
Dim jSession As JavaSession
Dim jClass As JavaClass
Dim jObject As JavaObject

Sub Initialize

    Set jSession = New JavaSession()
    Set jClass = jSession.GetClass("MyClass")
    Set jObject = jClass.CreateObject

End Sub
```

To start `Java object` use (in `LotusScript` of `Button`):

```vb
Call jObject.Start() 'Call with parameters that you want to use in Java
```

To check state and show progress use (in `LotusScript` of `Timer`):

```vb
If jObject.getIsOver() Then
    s$ = jObject.getURL()
    'Show results
Else        
    i% = jObject.getCounter()
    'Show progress
End If
```