# Java Agent doesn't run in its own thread when called from Lotus Script

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have a Java Agent marked with **"Run in background client thread"**.
The agent runs fine when called by a formula statement like this:

```
@Command([RunAgent]; "MyAgent")
```

Which has the problem that I can't pass a document ID to submit my parameters.

Alternatively, I can call the agent with the parameters I want using Lotus Script:

```
Call shAgent.Run(doc.NoteID)
```

Or like this:

```
Call MyAgent.RunWithDocumentContext(doc)
```

But the agent doesn't run in its own thread in this case. I am aware that other [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739811/multithreading-a-java-agent) exist. But I would prefer to use agent for legacy reasons.

Is there a way to let the agent run in its own thread when called from Lotus Script or to pass parameters to it when called via Formulas without using environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters through profile document:

```
@SetProfileField("MyProfileDocument"; "MyField"; MyValue);
@Command([RunAgent]; "MyAgent")
```

To get value in Java just use this:

```java
//Your code
Document profileDoc = session.getCurrentDatabase().getProfileDocument("MyProfileDocument", null);
Vector value = profileDoc.getItemValue("SomeField");
//Your code
```